# Windows Laravel 5 Unable to Open Database File With SQLite and php artisan

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel

I´m getting started on learning Laravel, and I just got a problem trying to make the first migrate with php artisan

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | PDO Fetch Style
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
    | stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
    | array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
    |
    */

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => "sqlite",

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => storage_path('database.sqlite'),
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

I have created the database.sqlite file and I can access it via the SQLite comandline. However when running the migrate command I get:

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open de database file.
```

Can anyone help me out? I'm using Windows 8 as my main Operating System.

Comment: What are you using to host your site? XAMPP? Homestead?

Comment: I am using XAMMP. I run the sever with the `php -S localhost:8888 -t public` command

Comment: OK, you need to check the permissions of your `.sqlite` file to make sure your web server can write to it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please show me how to do that? I´m new to XAMMP and I don´t really know where can I change those permissions.

Comment: I'm unsure how to do it on Windows I'm afraid. On Linux there is usually a user called `www-data`, who you must write permissions, but I don't know the equivalent on Windows. By the way, if you are using `php -S`, you are not using XAMPP, you are using PHP's built-in server.

Comment: Are you using forge? or locally database?

Answer (score 1):

If the permissions allow to write on the folder just create the storage folders.

Note: If you are on Windows Os, just use [git bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) to use `linux terminal command`, a better approach to use terminal and to prevent windows prompt command restriction for developper.

e-g, this how I fix the problem.

in `config/database.php` :

```
'connections' => [

  'sqlite' => [
      'driver'   => 'sqlite',
      'database' => storage_path('database/databaseName.sqlite'),
      'prefix'   => '',
  ],
```

Then if you run on your terminal `php artisan migrate`, it returns you the `[PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file`

Create the path folder by your own, e-g in your terminal `mkdir storage/database/databaseName.sqlite`

Make sure the permissions allow you to write, then re-run the command `php artisan migrate`, it returns you the success message : `Migration table created successfully`.

Answer (score 0):

This is as a result name conflict you have to change the name of the database in .env file found in the root folder

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database.sqlite
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

and note the file extension of your database (.sqlite)